# Is there a template available for module creation in DotNetNuke(Evoq) 8?

Tags: dotnetnuke

I have just installed DNN8 on my windows 2012 R2 server and was trying to jump into module creation. Currently on a production server, I am  using DNN6 and from what I understand earlier module templates are not compatible with newer versions of DNN.

I have found [the latest module template builds](https://christoctemplate.codeplex.com/releases/view/574327) by Chris Hammond, but they do not include DNN8. Does anymore know where I may be able to find a module template or possibly when I could expect to see one available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where did you get info that says earlier module templates won't work?

I honestly haven't tried Evoq8, I'm a platform guy, but the templates work fine in DNN 7.4, which I believe Evoq8 is based on.

Comment: I thought DNN 7 was still based on webforms, taking a look at the web.config, Evoq8 looks to be have an MVC backend to it. I will try to use and configure the module template for 7.4 and try to get it to work for 8.

Comment: I don't think that Jump to MVC has happened yet. It was supposed to happen with DNN8 (breaking backwards compatibility) but DNN 7.5 got renamed to 8 (MVC support, but not a breaking change)

Answer (score 0):

Evoq 8 is based in DNN Platform 7.4 and is WebForms only.  The new DNN Platform 8 release was originally going to be 7.5 but they decided to move it to a major release. DNN 8 is still a Webforms-based application, but now has support for MVC.  It is currently in CTP1 and the final release will not be out until end of May/early June 2015.

Because it is so early, there is no MVC template that I know of.  Charles Nurse (DNN Senior Architect) [wrote a preliminary blog on how to setup an MVC module project](http://www.charlesnurse.com/Blog/Post/1563/DNN-Loves-MVC-1-Introduction) for the upcoming DNN8 release.

I will likely do a DNNHero training on this topic in May and will have an MVC template ready close to the official launch of DNN 8.